# Sql query to check combinations and match it to the given combination

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, mapping, combinations

I've a scenario in Sql where I've following schema.

[image]

If I have 3 items in the Item table then one unique combination of all the items will be assigned to a user. For ex:

Items:
1
2
3

Then combinations will be: {1}, {2}, {3}, {1,2}, {1,2,3}, {1,3}, {2,3) all are unique combinations. 
Any of these combination will be assigned to a single user.

Now I want to find out given combination belongs to which user, how can I find that? For ex: I'll pass items list {2,3} then it should return the userid who is having that combination from the table UserItemCombinations. {2,3} is passed as comma separated string to a SP. I've taken 3 items as example, this table may contain n number of items. Users number will be dependent on the number of combinations. For ex: For three items there are 7 combinations so 7 users will be there user table.

Comment: how big n could be? For example, if it's limited to 32 or 64 you could use bit masks for better performance

Comment: @Dmitry: it may go upto 1k or more

Comment: How often the data in UserItemCombinations is supposed to change? May be it makes sense to write SP or trigger that will cache combinations in some field in User? That's because the query is too time-comsuming if it would go from stratch, I guess.

Comment: @Dmitry: There wont be any updates in that table, either delete or add but even that is rare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UserItemCombinations will have one row for each user-item, and one user can have only one combination, so if the query combination is {2,3}

```
select userid from user where userid not in 
  (select distinct userid from UserItemCombinations where itemid in 
                 (select itemid from item where itemid not in (2,3));
```

Comment: For any particular row, if `itemid in (2,3)`, I can guarantee `itemid not in (1,4,5,6,7)`, and vice versa. You need to consider multiple rows.

Comment: How can I use [not in], because that makes me dependent on items table in which I dont have control on number of items.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: You got me.. Edited now

Answer (score 1):

If there's not too much updates in `UserItemCombinations` and the performance of the desired query is critical enough, you would make additional field in `User` table, i.e. `Items` and create SP that fills in those values per every user. Stored proc will select sorted items per each user in loop and concatenate them into one string to put in `User.Items` field. You can also make trigger on `UserItemCombinations` for `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` and recalc the value again.

You may also create index on that field.

Answer (score 0):

select userid from UserItemCombinations where itemid in (2,3) and itemid not in 
(select itemid from Item where itemid not in (2,3));

Comment: For any particular row, if `itemid in (2,3)`, I can guarantee `itemid` is not equal to any other value. You need to consider multiple rows.